# Как читать записывающийся файл?

Tags: javascript, http, потоки-данных

Эксперементирую с проектом по стримингу видео. Пишу поток IPTV в mp4 на диск средствами ffmpeg. Проблема в том что файл живой и мне нужен в актуальном состоянии, передавать в плеер так не получается.
На данный момент, когда я перехожу по адресу localhost:3000 получаю видео, проигрывающееся  с начала, если руками перемотать в конец воспроизведение останавливается

Вот код:

```
var http = require("http");
var fs= require("fs");

http.createServer(function (req,res){
res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'video/mp4'});
var rs= fs.createReadStream("3.mp4");
rs.pipe(res);
}).listen(3000);
```

Первое: как отдавать всегда актуальный файл?

Второе: как начать отдавать файл не с начала?

Comment: Я думаю, стоит поставить Nginx, и не мучать NodeJS. Для стримминга самое оно. И перематывать также возможно. Погуглите "nginx + ffmpeg = rtmp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

задача была в трансляции файла на живую.с этим справилась бибилотека ffmpeg

Answer (score 1):

Первое: Вы всегда отдаете актуальный файл используя `stream`, который в свою очередь создает поток данных, которые читаются на клиенте, в порядке поступления данных и в случае когда мета информация о видео уже получена и показан таймлайн видео, это не значит что видео загружено. Поэтому когда Вы перематываете видео на время, данные для которого еще не загружены возникает ошибка.

Второе: Насколько мне известно то нет.